# Освобождение загруженного ресурса

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ресурсы

Есть консольная программа с бинарными ресурсами (Windows). Нашел, как загружать, записывать в файл и так далее -

```
HMODULE hMod=GetModuleHandle(NULL);
if(!hMod) { /* Error */ }
HRSRC hRes=FindResource(hMod,"Data",RT_RCDATA);
if(!hRes) { /* Error */ }
HGLOBAL hGlob=LoadResource(hMod,hRes);
if(!hGlob) { /* Error */ }
char * array=(char *)LockResource(hGlob);
if(!array) { /* Error */ }
unsigned int dwFileSize=SizeofResource(hMod,hRes);
if(!dwFileSize) { /* Error */ }
```

Все работает. Но если я верно понимаю прочитанное, то этот ресурс остается в памяти [до конца работы программы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-lockresource).

> The pointer returned by LockResource is valid until the module containing the resource is unloaded. It is not necessary to unlock resources because the system automatically deletes them when the process that created them terminates.

А у меня их много, я потому и ресурсами их делал, чтоб в памяти не держать. А как его из памяти выгрузить, когда он больше не нужен? Ждать, когда программа завершится - не дело.

Answer (score 1):

Windows автоматически управляет ресурсами, а выгружаются они при выгрузке модуля к которому относятся, это можно сделать функцией `FreeLibrary`. Некоторые типы ресурсов требуют дополнительного явного внимания, подробности описаны здесь: [Finding and Loading Resources](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/finding-and-loading-resources). `LockResource` же нужно использовать для того чтобы ресурс не был выгружен до конца работы с модулем, т.е. отключить автоматическую выгрузку.

Comment: У меня же нет `LoadLibrary`, я же не откуда-то тяну ресурсы, а из собственного exe - как же я могу писать `FreeLibrary`? А если у меня ресурсов на 100 гигабайт? Что, так и будет все в памяти?... Всякую мелочевку можно выгружать - типа пиктограмм... а `RCDATA` как же?

Comment: Возможно, ресурсы не очень подходят для хранения очень больших данных. Но, их можно хранить и в отдельных файлах, загружаемых через `LoadLibrary` в которых будет лишь одна ресурсная секция, тогда их можно будет выгружать.